# Fetching id's of all the distinct records in django

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

**Suppose we have a table with multiple records. Each record contains an awb number field.There are some duplicate awb numbers. I want to filter out all the distinct awb numbers with corresponding id's so that i can exclude all the distinct awb numbers on the basis of their id's from table to swipe out the redundant data.**

*what i am trying is following and not leading me any where:*

```
a= x.objects.filter(customer_id = 6).values('awb').distinct()
```

but this is only giving me awb and can't use this to reduce redundancy.
if i pass `.values('awb','id')` then also i fail as it says all the records are unique with this combination.

Comment: you are missing a `.` before `distinct()`. Try this `x.objects.filter(customer_id = 6).values('awb').distinct()`

Comment: thanks @BillyFerguson.

Comment: Yeah based on that comment to my solution @AnujMasand my solution is very wrong. You should be able to do it with `values` chained to `distinct`. Since that didn't work, I don't know what to say...